# Does completing challenges in Modern Warfare 2 MP improve your skill?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Does completing challenges in Modern Warfare 2 MP improve your skill or are these challenges just "for fun"?

I've heard people say that "completing Marksman I challenges make you aim better", or "completing marathon challenge makes you run faster". Are they right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they neither do improve your assist nor they are just for fun.
Completing marksman challenges only unlock [weapon attachments](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Marksman_%28Challenges%29#Call_of_Duty:_Modern_Warfare_2), which might offer new tactical alternatives, depending on your playstyle.

There are bugs in the game where equipping a visor attachment (holographic, ACOG) actually *will* increase accuracy slightly whem aiming down sights on some guns (won't go into detail), but that is a different question.

Completing other challenges have various effects, namely they upgrade your [perks](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Perks) from basic to Pro.